# how to divide SUM(CASE...)es?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to gain percentage by dividing two SUM variables. But when I try the code below, it gives me 0 as result. How can I divide these two SUMs?

Thanks!

(SUM(Case When FinalApprovalDt is not null and ContractPayoutAmt > 0 Then 1 else 0 End) / SUM(Case when FinalApprovalDt is not null then 1 else 0 end)* 100) As WriteRate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force one of the `CASE` expressions to have decimal precision:

```
1.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN FinalApprovalDt IS NOT NULL AND ContractPayoutAmt > 0
               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
      SUM(CASE WHEN FinalApprovalDt IS NOT NULL
               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)* 100 AS WriteRate
```

I suspect that SQL Server treated both `CASE` expressions as integers.  When dividing integers, you would likely get truncation occurring.  So for a quotient less than 1, you would just see zero.

Note: I don't know why you are dividing by 100.  For a percentage, I would have expected you to multiply the numerator by 100.

Comment: @VBS Check Gordon's answer using `AVG()` for a possibly safer option, unless you are certain that the denominator could never be zero.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server does integer arithmetic, so 1/2 is 0 not 0.5.

You can write this by using a non-integer in the `case` expressions:

```
(SUM(Case when FinalApprovalDt is not null and ContractPayoutAmt > 0 Then 100.0 else 0 End) /
 SUM(Case when FinalApprovalDt is not null then 1 end)
) As WriteRate
```

Notice that I removed the `else` from the denominator.  This helps prevent divide-by-zero errors.

You can also write this without an explicit division as:

```
AVG(Case when FinalApprovalDt is not null and ContractPayoutAmt > 0 Then 100.0 
         when FinalApprovalDt is not null then 0
    End) as WriteRate
```

This does an average over all rows where the `FinalApprovalDt` is not null, using the logic for the other column.

Comment: Throwing myself under the bus +1, but your second `AVG` option is probably the best way to go here.  Unless of course there is no chance of the denominator every being zero.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this ( Multiple the SUM of the numerator with 1.0 to make it decimal otherwise you will get integer division. )

```
SUM(Case When FinalApprovalDt is not null and ContractPayoutAmt > 0 Then 1 else 0 End) * 1.0
     / SUM(Case when FinalApprovalDt is not null then 1 else 0 end) * 100.0 ) As WriteRate
```