# Calculate percentage difference between amount of occurrences in a SQL column and list in HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

I have been stuck on this issue for ages so hoping someone can help.

I have a MySQL table which contains 2 columns I want to analyse:

```
Country | Status
----------------
UK      |  Closed
Germany |  Open
UK      |  Open
Spain   |  Dead
Spain   |  Open
UK      |  Dead
UK      |  Closed
Germany |  Open
UK      |  Dead
France  |  Open
Germany |  Closed
etc for 200+ rows
```

What I want to do is list in column 1 of an HTML table  all of the different countries (so here would be UK, Spain, Germany and France) and then in column 2 list the percentage difference between rows with that Country ***and*** Status as 'Open' and rows with that Country ***and*** Status as Open ***and*** Closed (but not Dead).

The only thing is, it is not a set defined list of countries. So by tomorrow there might not be any "UK" or 3 new countries might have been added. If this wasn't the case I would be able to have SQL queries "hard coded" for each country (not ideal but would suffice).

I have tried the below SQL:

```
SELECT `country`, ROUND(IF(`status` = 'Open') / (`status` = 'Open' OR `status` = 'Closed') * 100.0, 1) AS `Percent` FROM `$table` GROUP BY `country` ORDER BY `Percent` DESC
```

But then this doesn't seem to work with my PHP:

```
$list = "";
$sql = "SELECT `country`, ROUND(IF(`status` = 'Open') / (`status` = 'Open' OR `status` = 'Closed') * 100.0, 1) AS `Percent` FROM `$table` GROUP BY `country` ORDER BY `Percent` DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$list .=  "  
    <tr>
        <td>" . $row["country"] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row["Percent"] ."</td>
        <td> N/A </td>
        <td> N/A </td>
        <td> N/A </td>
        <td> N/A </td>
  </tr>";
    }
} else {
        echo "<p>No rows for calculation</p>";
}
```

Since I am a novice, any help you can give me would be most appreciated and thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

So I played around with this a lot. In the end it was the answer provided by Gordon Linoff here: [how to divide SUM(CASE...)es?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48867420/how-to-divide-sumcase-es) that worked for me. My SQL statement ended up being:

```
    SELECT `country`,
(
    SUM(case when `status` = 'Open' then 100.0 else 0 end) / 
    SUM(case when `status` = 'Open' OR `status` = 'Closed' is not null then 1 end)
) AS percent
FROM `$table`
GROUP BY `country` ORDER BY `percent` DESC
```

I also solved this by having the SQL output the three columns above (country, first SUM and second SUM) and then doing all of the maths in the PHP code. However, I knew that it would be cleaner to have it all done in the SQL so eventually managed to settle on the above. I hope this manages to help someone else.